# What is the definition of $\sqrt[n]{a}$?

Tags: definition, radicals

My question is really simple. We know that the definition of $\sqrt{a}$ is the positive solution of the equation $x^2=a$. What about $\sqrt[n]{a}$ for the others $n$?

Can I say if $n$ is odd than $\sqrt[n]{a}$ is the real solution of the equation $x^n-a=0$ and if $n$ is positive then $\sqrt[n]{a}$ is the positive real solution of the equation $x^n-a=0$?

So in this case, if I'm right, we will have $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$ and $\sqrt[4]{16}=2$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the standard definition of $\sqrt[n]a$.

Comment: This is correct. But the asker should be aware that once you introduce complex numbers, there is a non-equivalent definition where you take the _principal_ $n$th root by some convention. With that, when $n$ is odd and $a$ is real but negative, the principal value of $\sqrt[n]a$ would not be real. That is why some software will claim that $$\sqrt[3]{-8}=1+i\sqrt{3}$$ See also [Wikipedia Cube root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Is it possible the equation $x^n=a$ (n odd) have more than one solution?

Comment: @user42912 In real numbers, no, that is impossible. In complex numbers, the equation always has $n$ solutions. If $a=0$ these are all equal to $0$, but if $a\ne 0$ we get $n$ distinct complex solutions. ___Addition:___ You can try asking _Wolfram Alpha_ about [third roots of -1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=third+roots+of+-1). It will give you all three complex roots. Only one of them is real. Another one of them is the _principal_ root. When it is understood from context that complex numbers are to be considered, one must decide whether to prefer the real root or the principal root.